# Why emulator not opening? (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2za3.jpg
Emulator(phone) won't open. What is the problem?

### Output: Hardcoded string "Button", should use @string resource

when another emulator(phone) is installed it gives this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/54dEY.jpg

Output: The package was not installed. Please check you do not have it installed under any other user. If the package does show up on the device, try manually uninstalling it then try again. You should be able to uninstall the app via the Settings app on the device.

---

NOW
I deleted the old app links. The second error is over. The first error persists. The emulator does not open on the phone.

Comment: I deleted the old app links. The second error is over. The first error persists. The emulator does not open on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

> Output: Hardcoded string "Button", should use @string resource

This is a warning not an error. This warning would not affect the app running.  I was able to reproduce this when set the text like below.

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image]

If you want to fix the warning, add a `Strings.xml` in you value folder of Resources. Strings.xml is a string table to help with localization of the application.

[image]

Add the codes below into Strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <string name="Button_Text">Hello</string>
</resources>
```

And use it in your Layout:

```
  android:text="@string/Button_Text"
```